# Limited resolution in CentOS7 VirtualBox despite successful install of guest additions

Tags: virtualbox, centos7

I've spent all week trying to find an answer to this issue through google

I have installed VirutalBox 6.0.0 on a Windows 10 64-bit host, and I have created a VM and installed the latest CentOS 7 iso (CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1810). I have installed VirutalBox Guest Additions in the guest; there were no errors during the installation, and I'm enjoying some of the VirtualBox features that require Guest Additions (e.g. shared clipboard, shared folders, drag-and-drop, etc).

My only problem is that my resolution is limited to sizes no greater than 1024x768 and the "auto-resize guest display" option in VirutalBox is greyed out. I've tried setting up new VMs. I've tried reinstalling guest additions. I've tried reinstalling guest additions after updating the kernel to the latest version, and without updating the kernel at all. I've verified that I have all of the necessary packages to build against my current version of the kernel (e.g. kernel-headers, kernel-devel, etc). I've verified that systemctl shows the guest additions services as starting successfully. I've tried modifying my grub configuration to use vga=ask and selecting one of the alternative resolutions available there, but CentOS never finishes booting if I do that.

I am at wit's end. Does anyone have any other ideas?

Versions: 
Windows 10 64-bit host
VirtualBox 6.0.0 
CentOS 7 guest using CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1810.iso

Comment: I presume you maxed out the **Video Memory** slider in the VirtualBox display settings?

Comment: That's correct; video memory is maxed out (at 128 MB) and I've tried with and without 3D Acceleration turned on, then checking if I can change the resolution, then reinstalling Guest Additions, and then checking if I can change the resolution again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying an insane number of combinations, I was able to get this working with the following procedure

1) Install clean CentOS7

2) Update to latest kernel

3) *Remove* all kernel packages for the old kernel version

4) Build VBoxLinuxAdditions

What was weird was that this procedure didn't work for the older kernel (e.g. the one that came with my fresh CentOS7 install, prior to updating it with yum); the CentOS7 installer was installing the headers for the newer kernel even if I hadn't installed the newer kernel yet. So there was some sort of version mismatch between what VirtualBox thought it was building against vs what it was actually building against, resulting in nothing working until I had removed all traces of the old kernel.